# Data Binding property with string in SAP UI5

Tags: string, data-binding, properties, sapui5, formatter

I have a table with column "Employee Name".

On the click of any of the rows, I want to navigate to another view which has a object header, in the title of which I want to display:

`<ObjectHeader
      binding="{/data/}"
      title="Information of Employee: >>Employee Name<<"`

How do we bind a string and a data value together in a property?

Is formatter needed for this?
If yes, can you please guide me on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Expression Binding (or Complex Binding).

This is a beta feature but it is used by SAP in their Fiori Apps. So you are fairly safe to use it.

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/guide/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0.html